# Angular regex find all instances except inside `a` tag and wrap results with `span` won't return anything

Tags: angular, regex

I'm trying to write an Angular pipe where I find all instances of `query`,
but not between the `a` html tag and wrap the result with `<span class="highlight">match</span>.`

For example:
query = 'cat'
`this is some text for a cat` becomes `this is some text for a <span class="highlight">cat</span>`
`this is some text with a link <a href="link-to-a-file-named-cat.pdf">Some text</a>` stays the same.

I tried 2 solutions but both don't do anything:

```
     const expression = `^(?!.*<a\\b[^>]*>.*${query}.*<\/a>).*${query}.*`;
     const regex = new RegExp(expression, 'gm');
     const match = text.match(regex);

     if (match) {
       text = text.replace(regex, `<span class="highlight">${match[0]}</span>`);
     }
```

```
    const regex = new RegExp(query, 'gm');
    return text.replace(regex, (match) => {
      // Check if the match is inside an <a> tag
      const tagRegex = /<a[^>]+>/gi;
      const insideTag= text.substr(0, text.indexOf(match)).match(tagRegex );
      if (insideTag && insideTag.length > 0) {
        // Return the original match without any modification
        return match;
      } else {
        // Return the modified match
        return `<span class="highlight">${match}</span>`;
      }
    });
```

Comment: I am trying to understand the significant difference between `a cat` vs `a link`.

Comment: wdym exactly? 'cat' is just an example, could be anything, the query I'm looking for just can't be between an 'a' tag like <a href="....">...</a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add your query variable at the end of the new regex (below) construction.

The stml is what to edit.

What it does is to writeback the tags until it finds the query string
outside of tags then modifies that string with the "span" or whatever you want.

https://regex101.com/r/Q2xxyZ/1

```js
var query = "query string";
var stml = "\
    <body class=\"mediawiki query ltr sitedir-ltr ns-0 ns-subject page-International_English_Language_Testing_System skin-vector action-view vector-animateLayout\">\
    <div id=\"mw-page-base\" class=\"noprint\"></div>\
    <div id=\"mw-head-base\" class=\"noprint\"></div>\
    <div id=\"content\" class=\"mw-body\" role=\"main\">\
    <a id=\"top\"></a>\
    and also a normal query string\
    <div id=\"siteNotice\"><!-- CentralNotice --></div>\
    "
    ;

    var rx = new RegExp("<(?:(?:(?:(script|style|object|embed|applet|noframes|noscript|noembed)(?:\\s+(?=((?:\"[\\S\\s]*?\"|'[\\S\\s]*?'|(?:(?!/>)[^>])?)+))\\2)?\\s*>)[\\S\\s]*?</\\1\\s*(?=>))|(?:/?[\\w:]+\\s*/?)|(?:[\\w:]+\\s+(?:\"[\\S\\s]*?\"|'[\\S\\s]*?'|[^>]?)+\\s*/?)|\\?[\\S\\s]*?\\?|(?:!(?:(?:DOCTYPE[\\S\\s]*?)|(?:\\[CDATA\\[[\\S\\s]*?\\]\\])|(?:--[\\S\\s]*?--)|(?:ATTLIST[\\S\\s]*?)|(?:ENTITY[\\S\\s]*?)|(?:ELEMENT[\\S\\s]*?))))>|([^<>]*?)" + `(${query})`, 'g' );

    stml = stml.replace(rx, function (match, grp1,grp2,grp3,grp4) {
       if (grp4 > "" )
          { return grp3 + "<span class=\"highlight\">" + grp4 + "</span>"; }
       else
          return match;
    });

    console.log( stml );
```

Comment: well it looks like you're right but in production code my regex works just fine so I'm just gonna leave it at this for now

Comment: and if there are going to be bugs I'm going for a different solution in stead of this regex mess, I'll just give all uploaded file names a random name

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked in the end:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'highlight',
})
export class HighlightPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(text: string, query: string): string {
    if (!query) {
      return text;
    }

    query = query.trim().replace(' ', '|');

    const regex = new RegExp(
      `${query}(?![^<]*>|[^<>]*<\/mux-video>|[^"'<>]*href\s*=\s*['"][^'"]*['"])`,
      'gi'
    ); // g = global, i = ignore case

    text = text.replace(regex, (match) => {
      return `<span class="highlight">${match}</span>`;
    });
    return text;
  }
}
```

Test:
https://regex101.com/r/URtfIc/1

Comment: I used chatGPT to write the regex :D

Comment: The regex search for 'query', but not inside img and mux-video tags and not inside the href="" part of an a tag (but between <a>text</a> it does match)

Comment: Howdy. You can't get a regex to work when a starting point is inside a tag, attributes, values etc.. https://regex101.com/r/rCUyvZ/1 What you can do is to match content outside of tags, even between specific tags, and from within tags, even excluding specific tags.